Run docker-compose down from within another docker container
I have two docker containers, A and B, that are spun up with docker-compose files. I want to be able to bring the container B down with the command `docker-compose -f docker-compose.B.yaml down' from within container A.
Is this possible?
I tried to mount container B's docker compose file and /var/run/docker.sock. But when I run the command using a sub process in python (again from within container A), I get a 'no resource found error'.
docker:
services:
  Service A:
    image: imageA:rel_1.0.0
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
      - /path/to/docker-compose.B.yaml:/projectA/docker-compose.B.yaml
.
.
.



python:
#docker-compose.py
import subprocess

compose_file_path = '/projectA_directory/docker-compose.B.yaml'
command = f"docker-compose -f {compose_file_path} down"

result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
logger.info(f"Command output: {result.stdout}")
logger.error(f"Command error: {result.stderr}")

Error:
ContainerA | ERROR | 2024-07-29T19:56:51-0600 | docker-compose.py:62 | Command error: Warning: No resource found to remove for project "projectA".


It's very easy to use the Docker socket to take over the entire host system, so programs shouldn't usually have access to it.  To use Compose in particular you need both the Compose file and the Compose project name (the name of the directory holding the Compose file on the host system) plus the Compose tool itself.  It's possible, but I'd try to design my application to avoid needing to do this.

It's possible.

Add call.sh file to the same directory as docker-compose.yml.

#! /bin/bash
nsenter -t 1 -m -u -i -n /bin/bash << EOF
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@192.168.0.101

$1

EOF

change 192.168.0.101 to your host ip address.
2. Modify your docker-compose files
  Service A:
    image: imageA:rel_1.0.0
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
      - /path/to/docker-compose.B.yaml:/projectA/docker-compose.B.yaml
      - call.sh:/projectA/call.sh
    privileged: true
    pid: host
    ipc: host


Execute /projectA/call.sh docker stop containerB_name in your python code.


Letting a container run arbitrary shell commands on the host as root? What could go wrong? What if the host isn't running an ssh server?

Yes, there are real security risks.
